# Django not loading font file referenced by relative path in css

Tags: css, django, fonts

I'm in debug and serving my static file with

```
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets/"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets/css/"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets/js/"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets/fonts/"),
)

{% load staticfiles %}
{% static ....... %}
```

Inside my static folder i have:

```
-css
--bootstrap.min.css
-fonts
--glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
--glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
--glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
--glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
-js
```

In the request I can see that the css (that is loaded correctly) has the following url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/bootstrap.css
```

and the font that is referenced in the css (but not loaded) by

```
url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')
```

has the following url in the request

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

Is there a way to serve the font files properly without changing there url in the css file ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `http://127.0.0.1:8000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` this url loads correctly, right? You're giving that url twice. So the CSS url should work, no?

Comment: my mistake i made a pasting error. I edited the post with the correct url used to load the css

Comment: Not the best solution but you can add an additional URL that serves font files from /fonts/ instead of /assets/fonts/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Django Project isn't loading Bootstrap glyphicons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130114/my-django-project-isnt-loading-bootstrap-glyphicons)