# My Django Project isn't loading Bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

When I load my page I got the following messages in my terminal:

```
Not Found: /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2                                                                                                           
[24/Aug/2016 17:19:36] "GET /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 404 2238                                                                       
Not Found: /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff                                                                                                            
[24/Aug/2016 17:19:36] "GET /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 2235                                                                        
Not Found: /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

My home_page code where I load this glyphicon is above:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bootstrapmin.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp
            <button class="btn-link" type="button"> OntoLogica</button>

        </a>         
    </div>
</nav>
```

My bootstrap files are in:

- My Project Folder

  - static Folder

    - bootstrapmin.css
    - style.css
    - fonts Folder

      - Here are the files that the Django couldn't find

What I've tried to do:

1. Move the files of the fonts Folder to the same path of the bootstrap
2. Move the fonts folder outside the static folder.

If you need any information I didn't provide, please ask and I will.
Guys, what is wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you run `./manage.py collectstatic`? Also, is the `My Project Folder` a folder for an app, or is it really the top level folder in your project? If it is an app, you can try `"{% static 'my_project_or_app/bootstrapmin.css' %}"` instead of just `"{% static 'bootstrapmin.css' %}"`.

Comment: Yes, I've run collectstatic. My Project Folder is the top level project. The command "{% static 'bootstrapmin.css' %}" works fine, because I can access bootstrap commands like navbars, etc. What doesn't work is the glyphicon specifically. Is something related to not find the fonts and the svg files I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Bootstrap's CSS defines a relative path to the fonts that looks like this:

```
../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

This means that the browser will try to look one directory up from where the CSS file is for a `fonts` directory. In the case of your project structure is means that it tries to fetch `/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` instead of `/static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` which is where they actually are.

The simplest solution is to stick to the [directory structure recommended in the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included-precompiled) and to put all of your CSS inside a `css` directory that sites on the same level as the `fonts` directory:

```
- static
    - css
       - bootstrap.min.css
       - style.css
    - fonts
       - glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

Obviously you now have to refer to the files with the `css` prefix:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

The more complex solution is to download a [customised](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) version of Bootstrap where you set a custom `@icon-font-path` (note the default: `"../fonts/"`). With your current project structure you would need to change it to `"/static/fonts/"`.